# Javascript - Reference object inside event method

Tags: javascript

I have a class that I define with a constructor like this:

```
var Snake = function(x, y) {
    this.MoveStates = {'UP': 0, 'DOWN': 1, 'LEFT': 2, 'RIGHT': 3};
    this.moveState = this.MoveStates.DOWN;
    window.onkeydown = this.handleInput;
};
```

In the `handleInput` method I want to be able to access the move state variables, but I'm having some trouble doing so. The method looks like this:

```
Snake.prototype.handleInput = function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87:  //W
            this.moveState = this.MoveStates.UP;
            break;
        case 65:  //A
            this.moveState = this.MoveStates.LEFT;
            break;
        case 83:  //S
            this.moveState = this.MoveStates.DOWN;
            break;
        case 68:  //D
            this.moveState = this.MoveStates.RIGHT;
            break;
    };
};
```

In this method the keyword `this` references the window object that I bound the event to, if I'm not mistaken. How can I  obtain a reference to the snake object?

Comment: `window.onkeydown = this.handleInput.bind(this);`

Comment: FYI Despite appearances (and the new class keyword), JavaScript does not have classes - it only simulates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in this way.

```
window.onkeydown = this.handleInput.bind(this);
```

Just [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the the current context while calling `handleInput` method on *`this`* object.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable at the start of the function and store `this` in it, then call from that:

```
Snake.prototype.handleInput = function(event) {
    var snake = this;
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87:  //W
            snake.moveState = snake.MoveStates.UP;
            break;
        case 65:  //A
            snake.moveState = snake.MoveStates.LEFT;
            break;
        case 83:  //S
            snake.moveState = snake.MoveStates.DOWN;
            break;
        case 68:  //D
            snake.moveState = snake.MoveStates.RIGHT;
            break;
    };
};
```

You can then reference your snake object using `snake` from that point on.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `snake` will just be a reference to `window`, or `undefined` in strict mode.